# Any Google API to limit the range of a Bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-device-discovery

I'm developing a simple android app that scans for nearby Bluetooth devices & pair with them. I'm wondering if there's anyway I can limit the discovery range such if any paired device goes out of that range, I'll be notified. Is there any API or any way I can achieve this?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

i never saw that ! That's not what Bluetooth was designed for, because the range of each phone change a lot, and you could find one phone that got 5 cm, another phone got 50cm.